# npm install robotjs failed duirng to building binaries

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend

when I run the command "npm install robotjs -g" it gives me this error.

> > robotjs@0.5.1 install C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\robotjs
> >     prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
>
> prebuild-install WARN install **No prebuilt binaries found**
>   (target=8.11.3 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=win32)
>
> C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\robotjs>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild ) C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py:891:
>   Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6 Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       import gyp   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp__init__.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       import gyp.input   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py",
>   line 891
>       except ImportError as e:
>                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17133 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\robotjs gyp ERR! node
>   -v v8.11.3 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! robotjs@0.5.1 install:
>   `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the robotjs@0.5.1 install script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-29T09_19_13_980Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install (and run) robotjs in ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install -y nodejs npm
sudo apt install -y libxtst-dev
sudo apt install -y libpng++-dev
npm install robotjs
```

Got some warnings, but robotjs was successfully installed :)